# Is it possible to create a migration in a c# code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I need to create a migration from my C# code for a custom scaffolder.
Process :

1. Create the entity
2. Create Empty migration (Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges)
3. Fill migration

After some try, I can't call the nuget console to generate the migration and I didn't find methods to do it. So is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean runtime? Can you give the reason why?

Comment: My scaffolder generate my models from a selected entity but I need to create a sql-view. (I use my entities only for the database access)